# Hover toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some boxes div and they have hidden child element whenever I hover title of the box element hidden child is being appear it's ok but if I hover body element of the box too my body is dissapear how could I fix it ?

so what I want to do ?
if I hover title, body element must be apper (I did it)

but if I hover body, body musn't be dissapear

and that is why I if hover out of the box my body has to be hidden

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>



     <div class="box">
          <div class="title">Title</div>
          <div class="toggle">
            <div class="body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias et omnis optio ratione. Sint veniam, reiciendis aliquam atque impedit est earum. Placeat culpa, assumenda ad dolorum? Rerum hic nesciunt optio!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
             @copyright bla bla..
          </div>
          </div><!-- toggle-->
      </div>

      <div class="box">
          <div class="title">Title</div>
          <div class="toggle">
            <div class="body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias et omnis optio ratione. Sint veniam, reiciendis aliquam atque impedit est earum. Placeat culpa, assumenda ad dolorum? Rerum hic nesciunt optio!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
             @copyright bla bla..
          </div>
          </div><!-- toggle-->
      </div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
body{
  margin:50px;
}
.box{
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.title,.body,.footer{
  padding:7px;
}
.title{
  background:red;
}
.body{
  background:yellow;
}
.footer{
  background:black;
  color:white;
}
.toggle{
  display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box .title").hover(function(){
    $(this).parents(".box").find(".toggle").stop().slideDown();
  },function(){
    $(this).parents(".box").find(".toggle").stop().slideUp();
  })
});
```

[click to see demo](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/LRXYWw)

Comment: Fixed it: http://codepen.io/evolutionxbox/pen/PGxqvP =)

Comment: @evolutionxbox what was the problem ?

Comment: @Mahi it's a mystery! - the OP was targeting the title to hover, but only needed to target the box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are traversing to title, then trying to get parent elements

Try out this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".toggle").stop().slideDown();
  },function(){
    $(this).find(".toggle").stop().slideUp();
  })
});
```

Comment: Aw. You beat me to the answer! (although I did answer as a comment...)
http://codepen.io/evolutionxbox/pen/PGxqvP

Comment: Super cool! Just post it as answer. I didn't notice. @evolutionxbox

Comment: very well great

Comment: @recruit_man if you think the answer is helpful, accept the answer by clicking tick symbol next to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try Out This

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box .title, .toggle").hover(function(){
    $(this).parents(".box").find(".toggle").stop().slideDown();
  },function(){
    $(this).parents(".box").find(".toggle").stop().slideUp();
  })
});
```